# Embedding Phrase using Recurrent Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, tensorflow, word2vec

I am trying to get a word2vec embedding of a given phrase using an LSTM RNN encoder. 
For example, "How are you?" => [some word2vec representation]

I have pretrained model of word2vec(i already wrote an implementation for this) which gives me the word2vec of words but I am not sure how to get the word2vec given a phrase(which is a sequence) using a lstm encoder. 
I am trying to use TensorFlow(in Python) to do this.

Lets say I have the word2vecs of each word in the phrase how do i find the word2vec of the entire phrase using an lstm encoder(in TensorFlow with Python)?